# Deep array walk and output indentation

Tags: php, recursion

I have the following array structure, which is generated from a database:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [parent] => 1
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [parent] => 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [parent] => 1
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [parent] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [parent] => 4
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 6
                                            [parent] => 5
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

What I'd like to do is present this information in a HTML `<select>` box, with correct indentation to indicate the structure. So, for the given example, the result should look something like this:

```
- Select category
- Category 1
   - Category 2
     - Category 3
   - Category 7
- Category 4
   - Category 5
     - Category 6
```

I am currently looping over the content using PHP's `RecursiveIteratorIterator()` class, which works to output all of them, but I can't figure out how to include the indentation. Here's the code I have now:

```
$html = '<select>';

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($tree), RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach($iterator as $i => $cat)
{
    if($cat->id != '')
    {
        $option = new self($this->_db, $cat->id);
        $html.= '<option value="'.$cat->id.'"';
        $html.= '>'.$option->name;
        $html.= '</option>';
    }
}

$html.= '</select>';
return $html;
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction. Essentially, all I want to do is pad the option text by `x` spaces per nest depth.

Comment: You are wanting `optgroup` but you can only select the deepest option. The higher indents are only labels. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup

Comment: No, that's not what I want, because there are essentially an unlimited level of children. `optgroups` cannot be nested.

Comment: Neither can options. What you want can't be done. At least not semantically. To get the options to indent, you'll have to cheat it and add the indentation space in the option text, like `<option>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Category 1</option>`

Comment: I know... That's what I want to do, see last sentence: **Essentially, all I want to do is pad the option text by `x` spaces per nest depth.**

Comment: So you just need some way to tell how deep you are in a given array?

Comment: Yes, as an integer indicating `level` or some such, so that `str_repeat` can be used.

Comment: Have you looked at `getDepth()` method? http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getdepth.php

Comment: Fantastic - thank you! If you wish to add this as an answer I will accept same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to pad the option name, you could use [`RecursiveIteratorIterator::getDepth`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/recursiveiteratoriterator.getdepth.php) and add the padding multiplied by the current depth:

```
$option_padding = str_repeat("&nbsp;", 4 * $cat->getDepth() );
```